# Google Sies API-how to get sites name of a user via 2-legged oAuth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am a admin user. I want to know the sites name of all users individually using 2-legged oAuth in google apps.
I am able to get all sites name in a domain but its not specify, that which site is created by which user.

```
var url='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/domain.com/?include-all-sites=true'
  var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)
```

This code worked for to get all sites in a domain. There is any way to find sites name of a specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stay within native Apps Script and use the getAllSites method.

```
SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, start, max)
```

It's undocumented but [you can find references to it](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sitesapp.getallsites%22) and I have production scripts that use it daily.

Then you can use `Site#getOwners` to get the owner(s) of a site. The My Sites UI uses this info to display sites to users.

Comment: Thanks Peter Herrmann for your answer...now this problem has been resolved. I just make call to the site url by urlFetch(), that would return the json data. In that response I found all required information .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apps Script doesn't support a 2-legged OAuth model.